# How to deep copy an entity excluding id's of it's relations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orika

I'm using Spring with Spring Data JPA, I've encountered a problem with deep copying a complex entity. The entity `A` has 10 one-to-many relationships (only one is shown here for brevity), I want to deep copy this entity without the id fields of the nested objects `B`.

I want to avoid using reflection due to performance penalty. Using Orika I've manged to exclude the id of `A` but failed to exclude the id's of the nested objects.

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    //...

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private Set<B> items;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    //...

    public B() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

As you can see I've tried to exclude the id of `B` by registering a custom `MapperFactory` but it doesn't work as expected. Only the id of `A` is excluded but the elements of collection `items` still have their id's.

```
A source = fetchFromDb();
MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
        mapperFactory.classMap(A.class, A.class)
                .mapNulls(true)
                .exclude("id")
                .exclude("items['id']")
                .byDefault()
                .register();
        MapperFacade mapperFacade = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();

        A dest = mapperFacade.map(source, A.class);
```

How to achieve my goal?
note - I'm not locked to Orika, any other solution is welcome.

Comment: 'I want to avoid using reflection due to performance penalty' , you use spring,hibernate... it's reflection.  with spring util or apache you can do it if you don't want with reflection directly

Comment: if you were really concerned about the *performance of reflection* you would not be using Spring or Hibernate or Orika which 100% rely on reflection for everything they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue by [implementing a custom `ClassMapBuilder`](https://gist.github.com/medvednic/93e83899a14c4a590b5217bd4a999cce) for Orika mapper and overriding it's `byDefault()` method.
Now When the mapper is used to copy the container class, every field which has the `Id` annotation is excluded - it effects all nested single and multi-occurance elements.

To make the mapper use a custom `ClassMapBuilder`:

```
  MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory
            .Builder()
            .classMapBuilderFactory(new IdExclusionClassMapBuilder.Factory())
            .build();
```